# Rotation issue in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app in dragging and dropping image views from scroll view. After dropping I want to rotate images separately when user touches that which I have dropped. Here i can able to rotate only lastly dragged image.
I cant able to rotate the previous dragged image.
I use this code in touches moved to rotate

```
[myview setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([myview transform], angleInRadians)];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the UIRotationGestureRecognizer

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
rotationGesture.delegate=self;
[YourImageview addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];


- (void)rotatePiece:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 {
     [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
    [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
}
}
```

Comment: I need in UITouches Moved..plz help me

Comment: you can use the panGesture, rotationGesture, and pinchGesture, to drag,increase and decrease scale size, rotation

Comment: just check out this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

Comment: what is adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognier function